# SQL Query: How to find data from the most recent date that isn't blank?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select whse,sum(pspq)
FROM Table 1
where rwd in ('3','17','21','40') and xone <> 'J'and pln not like 'H%' and rwsd in 
    (Select Distinct asw
     from Table 2
     where xtp = '743' and xcf = '003' and adc = '12' and 
     CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles','Europe/Amsterdam', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(concat(Try_To_Date(to_char(dt), 'YYYYMMDD'),' ',Cast(To_Timestamp(LPAD(to_char(tm, 'FM000000'), 6,'0'), 'HH24MISS') AS TIME)))::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
        Between '2024-01-17 00:01:00' AND '2024-01-17 23:59:00'
)
group by whse
```

Right now I have this query where I have to manually change the dates I want to look for. Rather I would want the query to automatically pull the information for the latest date that isn't blank. Weekend dates typically doesn't have data so I want to skip those and pull the latest information from Friday(Or a different day if its a holiday).

- Any help in making it better would also be greatly appreciated!

This is run on Snowflake, so this is using the SQL available on the platform

Thanks!

Not sure what to try as I don't have much experience in this.

Comment: Blank? Do you mean null? Column data type?

Comment: `distinct` isn't a function, it's a _set quantifier_. `select distinct` gives you distinct _rows_. Simply write `Select Distinct asw ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: HI @jarlh as no data is entered during the weekend days, its just blank. and Thanks for the top on making the code clearer, I just amended on my actual query

Comment: Hi did you try using the Is Not Null and see if that works, if you give us some data example it will help us .

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: Logic is using below code to get max date having rows and then using that date as filter to get the data
Logic

```
SELECT dt ,COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE2
group by 1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Full code

```
select whse,sum(pspq)
FROM Table 1
where rwd in ('3','17','21','40') and xone <> 'J'and pln not like 'H%' and rwsd in 
    (
Select Distinct asw
     from Table 2
     where xtp = '743' and xcf = '003' and adc = '12' and 
     CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles','Europe/Amsterdam', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(concat(Try_To_Date(to_char(dt), 'YYYYMMDD'),' ',Cast(To_Timestamp(LPAD(to_char(tm, 'FM000000'), 6,'0'), 'HH24MISS') AS TIME)))::TIMESTAMP_NTZ) = 
        (select max(dt)
from (
--CODE
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles','Europe/Amsterdam', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(concat(Try_To_Date(to_char(dt), 'YYYYMMDD'),' ',Cast(To_Timestamp(LPAD(to_char(tm, 'FM000000'), 6,'0'), 'HH24MISS') AS TIME)))::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)) dt ,COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE2
group by 1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY dt DESC
)

) 
group by whse
```

let me know if it works